# Hackerrank Minimum swaps 2 - loop goes to infinity from a small change in code

Tags: python, arrays, loops

This challenge asks that you find the minimum number of swaps to sort an array of jumbled consecutive digits to ascending order. This is the correct function for the question:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    n = 0
    i =0
    while i < len(arr):
        index = arr[i]-1
        if arr[i] != arr[index]:
            arr[i], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[i]
            n+=1
            print(arr)
        else:
            i+=1
    
    return n
```

However if I get rid of the index = arr[i]-1 and replace index with arr[i]-1 everywhere like this:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    n = 0
    i =0
    while i < len(arr):
        
        if arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]:
            arr[i], arr[arr[i]-1] = arr[arr[i]-1], arr[i]
            n+=1
            print(arr)
        else:
            i+=1
    
    return n
```

The loop goes to infinity and I cant figure out why this is the case.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "if I get rid of the index = arr[i]-1 and replace index with arr[i]-1 everywhere" In the original version of the code, if `i` changes, will that make `index` change? In either case, if `i` changes, will `arr[i]` change? If data is written into `arr`, could that change the result of `arr[i]`? Could it change the previously assigned value of `index`? Now - does `i` change within your program? Is data written into `arr`? Do you see why this results in different behaviour?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assignment_stmt)? The process is described there, and at the end there's even a simple example talking exactly about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[i], arr[arr[i]-1] = arr[arr[i]-1], arr[i]` first evaluates the rhs terms `arr[arr[i]-1], arr[i]` this is unchanged compared to using `index`, now think of them being stored in temporary variables `a` and `b`. Then it assigns to the lhs terms one by one. First `a` to `arr[i]` and only after assigns `b` to `arr[arr[i]-1]`, at this stage `arr[i]` has alreday changed so this is no longer equivalent to using `index`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks a lot.